# Should you put citations before or after interpunction?

Tags: citing, typography, punctuation

This probably also could go to English.SE, but I'm not sure.

When I want to cite a source for a complete sentence, you put the citation before or after the period?

And if you cite for a word, or figure, do you put it before or after the comma?

Please bear in mind my citations are not superscripted, here's an example:

> appropriate awards and punishments[4, p.415].

or

> appropriate awards and punishments.[4, p.415]

Equivalent:

> when, on January 28[3, p.4],

or

> when, on January 28,[3, p.4]

I have a feeling that for facts I should put it right behind the fact and before the comma, while for sentences it should be after the period, but I do not know for sure.

Comment: In any case you should put a space (even better a nonbreaking space, that is `~`) before the reference!

Comment: I concur with @Daniel, unless the citation is superscript. I always put them inside punctuation.

Comment: Yes, now that I have done that, it shows that it's much nicer to put the citation inside the punctuation. It shows much better what text the citation belongs to. Thanks :D

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Until now, I have never spotted non-superscript citation marks after a comma or period. In addition, the marks should be separated by a normal interword space or a non-breaking space, i.e.

> appropriate awards and punishments [4, p.415].

and

> when, on January 28 [3, p.4],

See page 2 of [this](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-1/mori/mori.pdf) PracTeX Journal article for another example.

Comment: what should you do when the quotation ends in an exclamation point or question mark? Is it the same thing?

Comment: Does it mean that superscript citation must mark after a comma or period?

Answer (score 14):

While it seems that @lockstep’s answer describes the more common style, there are also style guides that suggest to treat citations like footnote markers: If they refer to the whole sentence, put them after the full stop.

One example is the [Vancouver style](https://ilrb.cf.ac.uk/citingreferences/vancouver/page06.html).