# Punctuation around citations

Tags: citing

> Possible duplicates:
>
> - [Should you put citations before or after interpunction?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34414/should-you-put-citations-before-or-after-interpunction)

I use BibLaTeX and have three options to cite: `\cite` creates just text, like “Author, Year”. `\parencite` creates “(Author, Year)” and `\footcite` creates a footnote. When I cite something within the text, I usually use the following:

```
From \cite{source}, it follows that …
```

Which renders to:

> From Author, Year, it follows that …

However, when I want to attribute something at the end of the sentence, where do I put the puncutation when I want to attribute the preceding sentence? Before the period, after it? Another period after the citation?

1. This is a fact. (Author, Year) And another fact. (another Author, year)
2. This is a fact. (Author, Year). And another fact. (another Author, year).
3. This is a fact (Author, Year). And another fact (another Author, year).

The problem with 3. seems to be that it looks like the citation is attached to the *word* “fact”, not the whole *sentence*.

My field is Physics, and I would write in German and English.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: This looks more like an 'academic style' question than anything TeX-related. Author-year styles seem to prefer the third option (I'm from a subject area which uses numerical citations, so I have limited experience.)

Comment: You mean this should be migrated to Academia? How do you do this with numerical citations?

Comment: I can certainly see a case for migration. For numerical citations, my subject area (chemistry) tends to use superscripts after punctuation. A few journals use either 'in line' numerals (before punctuation) or superscript citations before punctuation (_e.g._ _Nature_). In any case, you are best looking at what lead publications in your subject area do, and following them as this will be what is expected of you by others.

Comment: In Germany you have a specific rule: DIN 1505-02. The correct terminology is "Kurzbeleg" or "Harvard-Method". In this case you can find 1 and 3 as legal options.

Comment: case 1 doesn't make sense -- without punctuation after the reference, it would logically be attached to the following sentence (although it's unlikely to be misunderstood). case 3 is the most logical, although the recommendation to find out what style is preferred in your area is always a good idea.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for the style of citing and should have been migrated to Academia. Too late now, pity.