# Achieve compatibility between biblatex and cite packages

Tags: biblatex, citing

Generating a bibliography with bibtex in combination with the cite-package leads to migrated punctuation characters while using supercript citations. 
For example, this code leads to the following output:

```
This is an example sentence\cite{example}.
```

This is an example sentence.[1]

Changing from bibtex to biblatex, I had to exclude the cite-package due to incompatibility.
Thus the above shown code leads to the following output, where the punktuation character is not moved:

This is an example sentence[1].

As the migration of punctuation characters is a, in my case, desired behaviour, especially when having citations in figure captions and using the "textformat=period" option of the caption package, I would like to know if there is any possible way to achieve this functionality wile using biblatex rather than bibtex.

Comment: Just as remark: See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34414/124577).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` also supports moving punctuation around, but only with `\autocite`. Just to address the title of your question: You cannot make `biblatex` and `cite` compatible - they are fundamental incompatible, but most of `cite`'s behaviour can be replicated with `biblatex`. So we don't need to.

If you use a `numeric`-like style, this is not enabled by default, you need to tell `biblatex` to move punctuation to the **l**eft of the citation with `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}[l]{\parencite}{\parencites}` (`autocite=inline` is the default setting for `numeric` styles).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}[l]{\parencite}{\parencites}

\begin{document}
Lorem.\autocite{sigfridsson}

Ipsum. \autocite{sigfridsson}

Dolor \autocite{sigfridsson}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

To my eye that does not look very aesthetically pleasing. You can see that the feature is designed for footnote numbers, where the result is nicer.

---

Your comment suggests you actually want `\supercite`. In which case we only need

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
```

to switch the `\autocite` style to `\supercite`.

Comment: Moving the punctuation works fine with your solution. Additionally replacing \parencite and \parencites by \supercite and \supercites respectiviely lead to the desired formattting of the numbers as superscript.

Comment: @leandriis Sorry, I must have missed you wanted to use `\supercite`. In that case the behaviour is already built in. You only need `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, autocite=superscript]{biblatex}`